# Why is my ggplot2 legend improperly sized when using gridExtra? [r]

Tags: r, ggplot2, gridextra

I am arranging several point plots with gridExtra. When I plot a single plot the legend is properly sized and in the correct location. It looks like this:

[image]

My problem occurs when I use gridExtra's `grid.arrange()` to plot several in a grid. The legends are not being resized with the rest of the plots and end up looking like this:

[image]

Here is the code for a plot and a line to create the grid:

```
b2 <- ggplot(y2, aes(Rain_discrete, Cum_stress))+
  geom_point(aes(color = Planting), size = 2.25)+ 
  guides(colour = guide_legend(direction = "vertical", 
                               title.position = "top", title = NULL,
                               label.theme = element_text(size = 8, angle = 0)))+
  theme(legend.justification=c(1,1), 
        legend.position=c(1,1),
        legend.margin = margin(1,1,1,1),
        plot.title = element_text(size = 9, angle = 0),
        plot.margin = margin(2,1,4,1),
        axis.title.x = element_text(size = 8, angle = 0),
        axis.title.y = element_text(size = 8, angle = 90),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size = 8, angle = 0),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 8, angle = 0))+
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0, 85), ylim = c(-30,420))+
  xlab("Discrete Rain")+
  ylab("Cumulative Stress")+
  ggtitle("2002")

grid.arrange(b2,b3,b4,b5,b6,b7,b8,b9,b10,b11,b12,b13)
```

I have manipulated the legend characteristics by dropping `label.theme = element_text(size = 8, angle = 0)` from the guide portion of the plot. My logic is that directly specifying text size prevented the plots from being adequately resized. This did not work. I cannot pinpoint the issue.

Why are the legends not appropriately resized with the use of `gridExtra()`? I am trying to structure the ggplot2 code in a way that forces the legends to remain in place and be scaled proportionately when using `gridExtra()`.

Thank you for advice.

Comment: Nothing to do with gridExtra as far as I can tell; legends have a fixed absolute size in ggplot2, unlike panels. You can make the device larger to fit all the content, or perhaps organise the  legends differently eg with multiple columns.

Comment: Your gridExtra package has been a fantastic addition to my library. Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the font size is the problem. Have your tried to reduce the size "globally" for the image? Like

```
ggplot(y2, aes(Rain_discrete, Cum_stress))+
  geom_point(aes(color = Planting), size = 2.25)+ 
  guides(colour = guide_legend(direction = "vertical", 
                               title.position = "top", title = NULL,
                               label.theme = element_text(size = 8, angle = 0))) +
  theme_grey(6) +
  theme(legend.justification=c(1,1), 
        legend.position=c(1,1),
        legend.margin = margin(1,1,1,1),
        plot.margin = margin(2,1,4,1))+
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0, 85), ylim = c(-30,420))+
  xlab("Discrete Rain")+
  ylab("Cumulative Stress")+
  ggtitle("2002")
```

Or by resizing the element of the legend extra?

```
  theme(legend.key.size=unit(1,'mm'),
        legend.text=element_text(size=6),
        legend.title=element_text(size=7))
```

Comment: The second option in your solution worked perfectly!

Answer (score -1):

Dnt know why it is happenning but you can try `cowplot` package to plot the same as alternative. https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cowplot/vignettes/introduction.html

Comment: Maybe that will end up being my solution. I will try it out.